# Autofac: How to pass parameters when resolving instance using Metadata Lazy

Tags: autofac

I can get a collection of the plugins by using the following call:

```
_schemas = _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Lazy<IPersistedModel,ISchemaVersion>>>();
```

Depending on the metadata, I want to create a different instance.

I can create an instance by simply accessing the Value property.

The problem is there is no way to pass a parameter when doing it this way.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the resolved instance registering the `OnActivating`, `OnActivate` take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OnActivatingActivated).